# How to remove the string range from list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart

How to check in for loop that if times is equal to starttime and endtime then remove range from 12:00 AM to 2:00 AM and print only (2:30 AM, 3:00 AM)?
Below is the sample code till now what i have done.

```
late List<String> times;
times = [
      "12:00 AM",
      "12:15 AM",
      "12:30 AM",
      "12:45 AM",
      "1:00 AM",
      "1:15 AM",
      "1:30 AM",
      "1:45 AM",
      "2:00 AM",
      "2:30 AM",
      "3:00 AM",
]
String starttime = "12:00 AM"
String endTime = "2:00 AM"

for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      if (times[i] == startTime) {
        print(i);
        times.removeAt(i);
        print(times);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just compare the 2 strings, like this:

```
late List<String> times;
times = [
  "12:00 AM",
  "12:30 AM",
  "1:00 AM",
  "1:30 AM"
  "2:00 AM",
  "2:30 AM",
  "3:00 AM",
]
String starttime = "12:00 AM"
String endTime = "1:30 AM"

for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
  if (times[i].compareTo(starttime)!=-1 && times[i].compareTo(endTime)!=1) {
    print(i);
    times.removeAt(i);
    print(times);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works! i have a question i updated the code and added 15-15 mins instead of 30-30 mins and if i try this line `(times[i].compareTo(starttime)!=-1 && times[i].compareTo(endTime)!=1)` it is not working what i expected. Would be really appreciated if you help in this.